# How to actiivate the virtual env/VSCode conda activate env giving CommandNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

When I use a new terminal in VSCode to activate the virtual env in Anaconda:

```
PS D:\vscodework> conda activate base
```

it gives the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
```

I have tried this command:

```
conda init powershell
```

And it gives the following information:

```
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\deactivate
no change     D:\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
no change     D:\Anaconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     D:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     D:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
no change     D:\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
no change     C:\Users\ǧ\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
No action taken.
```

Comment: Did you close VSCode and restart it again?

Comment: Maybe you should use CMD

Comment: Have you tried the built-in VSCode functionality for working with virtual environments?